# How do I stop IE rendering HTML inserted into textarea

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, textarea

Internet explorer renders the following code instead of just inserting the text.

```
$("textarea").html('<object width="700" height="408">...</object>');
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [CMS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392143/43465) to a slightly different question, don't use .html(), use .val().