# Editable text functionality using jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, hide, show, edit

I have an image button and when I click it I want an specific field to go from text to an editable textfield, kinda like a  dynamic edit button.

So I have the plain text with certain id (ie. id="text1") and when I click the button, the text changes to an editable field, maybe something like `$("#text1").hide();` and then `$("#field1").show();` but in between I need to give the field the value of the text, and then when I click the button save I should hide the input field and just show the text with the new value.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

Given an input field, a **paragraph** with `id="text1"` and a button.

```
<input type="text" />
<p id="text1">Lorizzle ipsizzle dolizzle sit amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing yo mamma.</p>
<button>Copy</button>
```

This simple jQuery will copy the text from the paragraph, hide it and show the input with the text from the paragraph.

```
$("button").click(function() {
   $("input").val(
       $("#text1").hide().text()
   ).show();
});
```

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/marko/x723g/2/).

Just for fun, I've written a small script that enables `<editable>` functionality for paragraphs. Just add a class of `.editable` to any paragraph and jQuery takes care of the rest. I haven't extended it to allow multiple edits and I almost started writing AJAX calls that save to the database because I'm bored. **But** since the sun is shining I thought I'd rather go to the beach. Here's my code and a sample.

```
$(".editable").each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("id", "orig-" + i);

    var $edit = $("<button />")
    .text("edit")
    .attr("id", "update-" + i)
    .click(function() {
        var $input = $('<input type="text" />')
            .attr("id", "edit" + i)
            .val($this.text());

        var $save = $('<button>Save</button>')
            .click(function() {
                var $new = $("<p />").text($input.val());
                $input.replaceWith($new);
                $(this).hide();
            });
        $(this).replaceWith($save);

        $this.replaceWith($input);
    });

   $(this).after($edit)
});
```

**[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/marko/x723g/4/)**

***You really don't need all the ID's but if you're gonna do a POST with new values, you can easily refer to the elements.***

Comment: I get the impression that the OP wants to change from a text-node (say a `p`) to a `textarea`, rather than from an `<input type="text" />`.

Comment: @David - You're right I completely misunderstood that. Have modified slightly to suit.

Comment: @Marko, so I saw. +1 for the edit, and the lorem ipsum from the *'hood* =)

Comment: @Marko - the code is almost perfect, but I should be able to edit it multiple times, not just one time

Comment: also, I just noticed that the id changes, it should not change at all.

Comment: @fgualda87, I'll try find some time to edit the solution or create a plugin!

Answer (score 0):

Not too bad.  The text goes into the value area of the text field.  So get it from the text area, save it in a temp variable, and put it in the textfield.

Actually, you don't even need the temp I don't think, it should look something like

```
$('#field1').val($('#text1').text)
```

Note this is untested.  You might find [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery) to be of value as well.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mod').click(function(){

    $('#text1').html('<input id="no" size="'+$(this).text().length+'" type="text" value="'+ $('#text1').text() + '">');
      
    $('#mod').hide();

    $('#sav').show();

    });

    $('#sav').click(function(){
           
    // here code to save data in database

    });   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <td id="text1"> text </td>
    <input type="button" id="mod" name="modify"  value="modify" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sav" value="save" />
    </table>
```