# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

To learn JavaScript I am writing a small text editor Google Chrome extension. But I keep getting this error: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. It happens whenever `tranquility.save();` is called, but not when `tranquility.open();` which is weird because they are basically the same, just switched the sides. `paper` is just a `<textarea>`.

```
var tranquility = {
 paper: document.getElementById("paper"),
 lastOpenedPaper: localStorage.getItem("lastOpenedPaper"),

 listen: function() {
    this.paper.addEventListener("keyup", this.save, false);
 },

 save: function() {
    localStorage.setItem(this.lastOpenedPaper, this.paper.value);
 },

 open: function() {
    this.paper.value = localStorage.getItem(this.lastOpenedPaper);
 }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It is called after `<textarea>` is created (unless it has to be the entire DOM)

```
<body>
    <textarea id="paper"></textarea>
    <script src="../js/application.js"></script>
    <script>
        tranquility.listen();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems like `document.getElementById("paper")` is returning undefined.

Comment: This answer may be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery/416295#416295

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working with two fixes

1.) Write the script after loading of paper textarea. It was done by placing script at the end of body.

2.) I found `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem` should refer to the variable name like in http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/ . In your code lastOpenedPaper would refer to null value in begining so it won't store value in that name so i tried replacing it with just. you can use other var name too or use varname directly as `localStorage.setItem('anyvarname', this.paper.value);`

code:

```
<script>
    var tranquility = {
     paper: document.getElementById("paper"),
     lastOpenedPaper: 'just',

     listen: function() {
        this.paper.addEventListener("keyup", this.save, false);
     },

     save: function() {
        localStorage.setItem(this.lastOpenedPaper, this.value);
     },

     open: function() {
        this.paper.value = localStorage.getItem(this.lastOpenedPaper);
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I had all ready done #1, and I had all ready manually set lastOpenedPaper equal to test, and manually created test and made it equal some arbitrary string. The load works fine, which means all the variables are pointing correctly, just save is being weird.

Comment: can you paste your code in pastebin or fiddle.net so we can check it ... try adding dubuggind code in save like consol.log or alert

Comment: it is the exact same as what I pasted except for the html (does not include head tag that loads a  currently blank .css, which could not cause problem)

Comment: i got it working by changing this.paper.value to this.value in save function. i hope thats code save function is being invoked by textarea so replaces the this object

Answer (score 1):

> It happens whenever
>   tranquility.save(); is called, but not
>   when tranquility.open(); which is
>   weird because they are basically the
>   same, just switched the sides.

Ah but they're not the same because:

```
save: function() {
    localStorage.setItem(this.lastOpenedPaper, this.paper.value);
},
```

This is potentially not okay, because `this.paper.value` could not be defined

```
open: function() {
    this.paper.value = localStorage.getItem(this.lastOpenedPaper);
}
```

Where this is setting a value to `this.paper.value`, so it being defined or not doesn't matter.

Also:

```
document.getElementById("paper")
```

This won't work if this code is not declared `onload` or after the `<textarea>` is created, because the DOM tree hasn't been built otherwise.

Comment: It is called after `<textarea>` is created