# jQuery - remove user input text from textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, textarea, jquery-ui-dialog, user-input

Okay I have a list of devices where i can select which to edit.
I have 3 states for the edit. When no devices are selected, when 1 device is selected or when x devices are selected.

The problem i have is when a user type some text in the textarea (commentField) and cancels the edit to edit another device, the text there was typed in the textarea won't disapere. It stays so when i get the new dialog for the new edit, the commentfield has the text from the old commentField (as if it wasn't cleared)

I have tried the following codes to remove the text (both when then cancel button is pressed and when i start a new dialog), but nothing works:

```
$("#commentField").text(" ");
$("#commentField").value = ' ';
```

Is there anyone who knows how to remove user-typed text from a textarea using jQuery??

Thanks in advance.

-Thor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set value of textarea in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You're looking for [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val):

```
$("#commentField").val('');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/q6eLV/

Comment: do you know why this doesn't trigger a change event in the textarea?

Comment: @user3281466: setting a value programatically doesn't trigger the `change` event. You could do that manually yourself if you wanted to by calling `.change` after setting the value.

Answer (score 3):

Since `textarea` is a input field it has a `value` property so you have to use `val()` method. Try this

```
$("#commentField").val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery it's actually `$("#commentField").val(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove text from the textarea like this:

```
$("#commentField").html("");
```

EDIT: this does not work, but I'd be really interested as to why. I always thought that the text between the `textarea` tags was innerHTML and `html()` is supposed to replace just that. Wouldn't it make sense to have textarea like input?  or is it just because textareas contain long amounts of text that would look tacky between quotation marks?.

Using regular javascript with innerHTML it works for me in FF6.
[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tq6s4/)

Comment: Actually, downvoting is unfair here; I was stuck with the same problem, hence the fiddle. I also assumed that, since it was between tags, `.html()` or `.text()` would have worked, but apparently not. Maybe jQuery has a special case for `textarea` so it uses `.val()` like all other inputs.

Answer (score -1):

1) `<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>`

2) `CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');`
3) `initiated = true;`
to write your text in you text area
1)`$("#editor1").val("your input value");`
to clean your text area
1) `$("#editor1").reset();`
tank you for reading this.

Comment: The question does not reference CKEditor.