# Load text into textarea via ajax call

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like to load some text retrieved from a dB into a textarea. The user clicks a link:

```
<a class="editlink" id="<?php echo $review['id']; ?>" href="#"><?php echo $review['title']; ?></a>
```

JQuery passes the ID to GO.PHP:

```
$(".editlink").click(function() {
    $.get("go.php", {param: $(this).attr('id')}, 
        function(data) {
            $('textarea#area1').html(data);
        });    
    return false;
});
```

GO.PHP retrieves the text from the dB:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id = ".$_GET['param']." "); 
while($review = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    echo $review['description'];
}
```

As confirmed by Firebug consolle, ID and the text are retrieved correctly. The probelm is that I'm not able to place the text into the textarea:

```
<textarea id="area1" rows="30" cols="55"></textarea>
```

I tried: .html(data), .text(data), .val(data) but none display anything. (Please note that the text in the dB may contain HTML tags that I would like to keep).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the text areas value.

```
$("#textareaID").val("value of text area");
```

I put this into a blank HTML doc referenced query in the head and it worked fine.

```
<form>
  <textarea id="test"></textarea>
</form>
<script>
    $('#test').val('testing');
</script>
```

Comment: I did tried "$('textarea#area1').val(data);" but it does not display anything.

Comment: I did try your code, and it all worked for me.  Since my answer was accepted did you fine the problem or did someone else accept it?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this

```
$('textarea#area1').attr('value',data);
```

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand. What's 'value'? 'data' is go to be filled by "echo $review['description'];" and, as said, Firebug consolle returns that the output is corrent. So what's 'value'?

Comment: check this post. may be of some help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

> I tried: .html(data), .text(data), .val(data) but none display anything.

As other answers have stated, .val(data) or .text(data) should work. ***Don't .html(data) with textarea, because won't work in internet explorer however, as it will remove html when used with textareas*** ([try this in IE](http://jsfiddle.net/bUNn2/2/)).  I would use the firebug console to ensure data is set, and look at your net tab to ensure everything is returning correctly. My guess is there is an error elsewhere.