# Variable values in a text area

Tags: html, variables, textarea

I want to print the value of a variable in a text area (in HTML).

```
var msg = trigger.find('span::last');
```

it is this msg variable's content that i want to display in a text area. How can i do this?

Thanks & regards!

Comment: What language you want to do that in?

Comment: Looks like JavaScript, probably using some framework like jQuery.

Comment: Looks like jQuery to me. In that case it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery --- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is jquery that you are using. You can set the value of your text area with something similar to the following code:

```
var msgContent = msg.text();
$("#mytextarea").val(msgContent);
```

Hope this helps.