# Change text inside textarea jQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea

I'm trying to change the text inside the textarea with `id="code"` but `$("#code").val(newtext)` doesn't work.. What could be the problem? I'm using CodeMirror for highlighting text inside, if this matters
Thanks

Comment: That looks good to me so can you show us on jsfiddle.net?  Do you get an error?  What's in `newtext`?

Comment: You need to show more of your code, something that shows the problem. `$('#code').val(newtext)` works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/FYkVT/

Answer (score 2):

[textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) does not have the value attribute; therefore, it better for you to use `.text()` function

```
$("#id").text(newValue);
```

Update: Well, I had this problem once in my old project, but after changing to .text(), then it works (got solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)). I know that `.val` could be applied, too, but if you get trouble like this (it could be because of your browser compatibility, version of jquery...) and you are sure that your selector code is correct, then choose either way (val or text)

Comment: *"The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and **textarea**."* (http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: this still doesn't work.. I went reading deeper and the problem is CodeMirror which generates the textarea. I tried many solutions I found, but none of them work for me.. Please help!

Comment: do you have $(document).ready(function() { //set value to textarea )}; on your page?

Answer (score 0):

```
encodeURIComponent($("#code").val(newtext))
```