# color values in a text area

Tags: django, jquery, django-templates

I want to fill a text area with values in a list obtained from Ajax request in a django app. 
Here is the list returned

```
{"listforeign": ["t", "t", "t", "g", "g", "g", "o"]}
```

here is the textarea where it goes.

```
<textarea rows="10" name="BaseP" id="id_BaseP" placeholder="Paste text here ..."
 cols="40" class="textarea">
```

The problem is

1. Append the values from the listforeign into the text  area.
2. the element "o" should be in color red

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All text in a `textarea` element will render with the same color, font etc. You cannot style a character or a word etc. differently.

As an alternative, try using a `contentEditable` DIV and serve out the `o` inside a span with a defined text color.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

To append values to a textarea, use the `.val()`-function from jQuery.

From [Set value of textarea in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery):

```
$("textarea#id_BaseP").val(json);
```

To parse the JSON you have, use JavaScript's JSON-parser. From http://www.json.org/js.html:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext)
```

The created object has the JSON-data as its fields.