# Not able to set the text in an textarea using jQuery and value method

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I've got the following markup:

```
<textarea id="hazaa"></textarea>
```

When I execute the following JavaScript in the console:

```
$("#hazaa").value
```

I get the print-out of what's in the box. However, when I try to execute this:

```
$("#hazaa").value = "shazoo"
```

the console notifies me back with *shazoo* but the text in the box doesn't change. Also, subsequent check of what's in the box returns the old, unaltered value.

It's been a while since I've done any jQuery-ing so it's probably something fairly obvious but I can't think of any resolution. I've googled for suggestions but [the best one I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery) actually discusses **properties that aren't there**! What am I missing?!

Executing the following two lines:

```
$("#hazaa").val
$("#hazaa").val()
```

produces:

> undefined
>   TypeError: Object # has no method 'val'

I trust fully that I'm to blame for it but I don't how how to proceed.   :)

Comment: `$("#hazaa").val` is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this -

*setter*

```
$("#hazaa").val("shazoo");
```

*getter*

```
var val = $("#hazaa").val();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/val/

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/E3kZy/1/

Comment: Works like a charm (as expected). What kind of stupid thing have I done now?!   :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set value by using `.val()`

> Set the value of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
   $("#hazaa").val('Your text here');
```

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

You can get the value using  `$("#hazaa").val();`

Comment: because there is no methods like .val

Comment: I'm getting an error message when I try to execute *.val()* and *.val("shazoo")*. Suggestions?

Comment: Hmm... I **assumed** that since I can execute *$* and get something other than error or null, I had jQuery available already... How can I check that the jQuery is there and has the correct version?