# How to apply string value?

Tags: jquery

Code:

```
$(".drpdwn")[0].options.value = "1"
```

I need to change this value to `"string"`

So, I coded as,

```
$(".drpdwn")[0].options.value = "string"
```

But, the value becomes as `""` in quickwatch.

How to apply string value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set value of textarea in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)

Answer (score 5):

`$('.drpdwn').val('string');`

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Edit:

As there is some confusion about this. `$('.drpdwn')` is a jQuery object representing all elements with the `drpdwn` class. This jQuery object has a `val` method. If you select only one of the matched objects using `$('.drpdwn')[0]` you get a DOM object (pretty much what you would get if you did `document.getElementsByClassName('drpdwn')[0]`). This obviously has no `val` method.

The better way of going around this, is making `$('.drpdwn')` more precise, so that it only matches the element you want to change. The easiest way is by giving your element an id (ala `<div id="myElement" class="drpdwn"></div>`) and selecting it with `$('#myElement')`. The other way would be by using the `value` property of the DOM object, like `$('.drpdwn')[0].value`. This will however break as soon as you insert an other element with that class before the element you want to change.

Comment: If I am changing any integer value in quickwatch..say for eg., "1" to "3" means it accepts. Why this happens ?

Comment: It's because the address is same and value is made different

Comment: Also, I am getting the error message as `Object doesn't support property or method 'val'` when I coded as follows `$(".drpdwn")[0].options.val('string');`

Comment: @JohnStephen `$(".drpdwn").val('string');` try this or `document.getElementsByClassName("drpdwn").value="string";`.

Comment: @JohnStephen I've added some more information about the difference between `$('x')` and `$('x')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery,

```
$(".drpdwn").val("string");
```

I think you're trying in JS. if so

```
document.getElementsByClassName("drpdwn").value="string";
```