# decode and encode HTML from php htmlentities in real time using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-entities, html-encode

Well this is the problem, i have a "pre" tag with encoded html using htmlentities() from php that shows correctly on website.

But then i want to redecode it to put it in a "textarea" to work with in real time. (like stackoverflow does for example). And then this text modified is encoded (again and again) in the "pre" tag with the new info.

I tried this but it seems that it doesnt work, because the textarea is allways empty. This is the code:

```
<script>
var t0=document.getElementById("textarea0"),
x0=document.getElementById('pre0');

t0.value=x0.innerHTML().html().text(); //dec
t0.onkeyup=function(){
x0.innerHTML=t0>.value.text().html(); //enc};
</script>
```

i dont really understand how this code works, i know is wrong because jquery is far away from my mind, i saw others similar questions related to this using `$('<div/>')` before encoding but I dont think that was the problem. (i repeat that i am blind on this)

(sorry if i do too many mistakes, im not english writer as you can guess, and im not using translators)

**EDITED**

Well first part works now, Textarea is filled with the content of the PRE and is decoded (with `<>`and that kind of things) for real work.

But i cant give it back to the PRE, putting them the new changes.

this is the actual code now:

```
var t0=$("textarea#textareaName0"),
x0=$('pre#xmpName0');

t0.val(x0.text()); //dec
t0.keyup(function()
{
x0.innerHTML=t0.val(); //enc
});
```

Any solution? (thank you so much)

**Final Solution**

In order to update content the code which work is:

```
t0.keyup(function()
{
x0.text(t0.val()); //enc
});
```

As you said, jquery can print on screen HTML without been interpreted so i DOESNT need encoding to avoid it.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually you do need encoding but text() is doing it for you. Incidentally, you should really start using meaningful variable names. I nearly gave up on your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is something like a HTML tutorial that shows HTML source, then you want that source to be edited verbatim (without all the `&gt;` stuff)

`var src = $("pre").text()` will give you the source in variable `src`.

`$("textarea").val(src);` should put it into the text area (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)).

Incidentally, `$(src)` gives you a detached DOM with the src, justs as `$('<div/>')` gives you a DOM containing one div. You seem to want the user to edit, not jQuery so you already have everything you need in `src` and don't need to create a DOM. You would only want to DOM if you wanted to insert elements from jQuery.

Comment: i modified a part of your code and it works, but i can give it back to the "pre" tag after the changes.
`var t0=$("textarea#textareaName0"),
x0=$('pre#xmpName0');

t0.val(x0.text()); //dec
t0.keyup(function(){
x0.innerHTML=t0.val(); //enc
});` Take a look on the EDIT part.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *encode* text that's flattened from HTML, using `.text()`. The HTML information is gone forever from it. And `.text()` returns a string, and it does not have a method named `.html()`.

At best, you can put the flattened text back into the textarea.

```
x0.innerHTML=t0.value;
```