# Change the text of the textarea via JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to create the jquery so that when i click an option of the select changes the text of the textarea for the option value

```
<p>¿Qué frutas te gustan?</p>
<form>
    <select size="6" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Naranja">Naranja</option>
        <option value="Sandia">Sandia</option>
        <option value="Melón">Melón</option>
        <option value="Ciruela">Ciruela</option>
        <option value="Melocotón">Melocotón</option>
        <option value="Plátano">Plátano</option>
        <option value="Coco">Coco</option>
        <option value="Piña">Piña</option>
        <option value="Higo">Higo</option>
        <option value="Fresas">Fresas</option>
    </select>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="60">Mis frutas preferidas son: Naranja, Sandia, Melón</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything. Anything at all??

Comment: Might I suggest at least attempting some javascript/jquery to show.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set value of textarea in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
<script>
    function updateTxtArea(ele)
    {
       $("#textArea").html($(ele).val())
    }
</script>

<form>
<select size="6" onchange="updateTxtArea(this)" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Naranja">Naranja</option>
    <option value="Sandia">Sandia</option>
    <option value="Melón">Melón</option>
    <option value="Ciruela">Ciruela</option>
    <option value="Melocotón">Melocotón</option>
    <option value="Plátano">Plátano</option>
    <option value="Coco">Coco</option>
    <option value="Piña">Piña</option>
    <option value="Higo">Higo</option>
    <option value="Fresas">Fresas</option>
</select>
<textarea rows="4" id="textArea" cols="60">Mis frutas preferidas son: Naranja, Sandia, Melón</textarea>
```