# escapeHTML with Struts2 <s:textarea /> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I know, the below code will display the value in HTML format like `<b>DATA< /b>`, will be displayed as `<b>DATA</b>`.

```
<s:property value="workItem.Note" escapeHtml="false"/>
```

How can we achieve same with `<s:textarea name="workItem.Note" value=""/>`?. Text area displays value in normal string format like `<b>DATA</b>` not in HTML.
Here I am assigning value from JavaScript that is coming from db in String format containing HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML `textarea` tag

```
<textarea name="workItem.Note">
   <s:property value="workItem.Note"/>
</textarea>
```

Comment: you are right sir. but I am assigning value from javascript into textarea. So, I think no benefit to use property tag inside textarea.

Comment: What a benefit to use javascript? I will grant you the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/415602/573032).

Comment: on page load, I m bringing a List from action, and creating some hidden fields iterating it. and on radio button, I m picking value of certain hidden field and setting its value to one Common TextArea. and that hidden field contains string with html tags. That's it.

Comment: On page load you should already have a field populated from the action when result has been executed. So you can use something`$("textarea[name='workItem.Note']").val($("input:hidden").val());`