# Why does appending my dynamic textarea to a div result in an empty textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to edit a div named meta description inside of a div named post by taking the html and creating a textarea with it then plugging it back in. I have it working for the Title, content, and even meta keywords, but for some reason the description's textarea just keeps coming up empty in the end.

```
    //---------------edit meta Description------------
var Description = metaDescription;
Description.show();
//save the html within the div
var ogDescription = "None"; 
if (metaDescription.html()) {
    ogDescription = $(Description).html().trim();
}
console.log('ogDescription = ' + ogDescription); 
// create a dynamic textarea
var editDescription = $("<textarea />"); 
editDescription.val(ogDescription);
console.log('editDescript val after adding === ' + editDescription.val());
console.log('editDescript html after adding === ' + editDescription.html());
editDescription.attr('class', 'editDescription')
            .css('height', metaHeight)
            .css('width', post.css('width')); 
// add the textarea 
Description.html("<p>meta Description:</p>"); 
$(Description).append(editDescription); 
//--end edit meta Description
```

Output

```
Title = Newly Added Post
Posts.js:79 Content = Testing 1, 2, 3
Posts.js:105 ogDescription = Testing 1,2 and u know 3
Posts.js:110 editDescript val after adding === Testing 1,2 and u know 3
Posts.js:111 editDescript html after adding === 
Posts.js:129 Keywords = none, for, now
Description html after === <p>meta Description:</p><textarea class="editDescription" style="height: 80px; width: 262px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textarea doesn't have a value attribute. Unlike input, the "value" of textarea is the content between the beginning and end tags. You will need to set the innerHtml instead using .html("blah") or .text("blah")

See [Set value of textarea in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the link you sent me to has the answer of "$("textarea#ExampleMessage").val(result.exampleMessage);" which is exactly what I am using "editDescription.val(ogDescription);"

Comment: Sorry, if you look further down, other responses go into more detail.

Comment: Are you able to inspect the element? Textarea should have an end tag. It is possible you created a custom attribute which is where the content is being stored

Comment: Thanks! By using .text() I get the right output "Description html after === <p>meta Description:</p><textarea class="editDescription" style="height: 80px; width: 262px;">Testing 1,2 and u know 3</textarea>"

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the textarea as follows

```
var editDescription = $("<textarea>" + ogDescription + "</textarea>");
```